# recycling getView forgets View states

Tags: android, android-listview

my problem is i have a listview with checkboxes visibility gone when clear button is selected checkboxes get visible i am stroing the states of checkboxes but problem is that when checkbox is checked it calls onCheckChange() and do the work to set state but when my view recylces it again setChecked to the stores states and again calls my onCheckChanged and i dont know why when i scrolls back up it doesnt restore my checked states...
this is my code

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final int currentPosition=position;

        View row=convertView;

        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);
            holder=new Feedbacks();
            holder.lvGuestName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.guestName);
            holder.checkBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.clearCheck);


            row.setTag(holder);

        }       
        else
        {               
            holder=(Feedbacks)row.getTag();             
        }

        if(showCheckbox)
        {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
        }
        else
        {
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.lvGuestName.setText(feedbackList.get(position).getGuestName());          
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(checks.get(position));
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    checks.put(currentPosition, true);

                }
                else
                {
                    checks.put(currentPosition, false);             
                }

            }                   

        }); 
        return row;                                     

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
holder.checkBox.setTag(position);

holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            Integer currentPosition = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString());
            if(isChecked)
            {
                checks.put(currentPosition, true);

            }
            else
            {
                checks.put(currentPosition, false);             
            }

        }                   

    });
```

Also there is no need of using a new View "row". Re-use the convertView instead of row and return it. You are wasting memory by using a View here. So just reuse convertView.